# Why do Nickel Manganese Cobalt batteries wear out before Lithium Iron Phosphate batteries?

Tags: chemical-engineering, battery, chemistry

Do NMC batteries lithium plate faster? Does the Solid Electrolyte Interface (SEI) grow faster on NMC batteries? Do they heat up more and therefore the SEI grows faster? Does the Iron stabilize the LFPs somehow? Is it because NMCs are typically charged faster?

I am having trouble finding resources which explain what is happening at the chemical/electrical/mechanical level.

Comment: conditions of use?

Comment: are you asking under what conditions this happens, or are you saying that NMC batteries are typically used in harsher conditions and therefore tend to wear out faster?